# If I'm eligible to max a Roth IRA, Do I ever considering putting money in both IRA types instead?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, roth-401k

Age 28 (Turn 29 in November)
Gross Income - 110,050
Retirement (At the start of 2015) - $12,000 in Roth IRA

My current contribution for the year is aimed at:

- 9,000 in Roth 401k
- 9,000 in Traditional 401k
- 5,500 in Roth IRA
- 1:1 on First 4% of Salary Plus Discretionary Contribution Based on
  Profit (Traditional 401k as a lump sum)

**However, I received advice that I shouldn't have zero balance in a traditional IRA.**

I know in the instance that if my MAGI exceeds a certain point, I can not contribute the maximum to the Roth IRA; a traditional IRA and subsequent backdoor is the way to go. But I am currently at a point where my income allows me to put the full $5500 in my Roth.

**Do I ever consider the thought to splitting my IRA contributions?**

Answer (score 7):

You can do the Roth IRA, but I think [your income is too high](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/2015-IRA-Deduction-Limits-Effect-of-Modified-AGI-on-Deduction-if-You-Are-Covered-by-a-Retirement-Plan-at-Work) to take a deduction on the traditional IRA.

[image]

By the way, this is the 2015 tax table -

[image]

You look like you are in the 28% bracket. A good place to be, but I'd be putting more money pre-tax in the 401(k) and consider converting in years that your rate may be lower. It's easy to get married, buy a house, and that same income puts you in the 15% bracket.

The truth is, no one can project 5 years out, let alone 40, and a mix like you have is as good an approach as any, even if I'd lean more pretax. Remember, your $4400 match is on the pretax side, so you are close to 50/50 as is.

Answer (score 5):

> I know in the instance that if my MAGI exceeds a certain point, I can
>   not contribute the maximum to the Roth IRA; a traditional IRA and
>   subsequent backdoor is the way to go.

My understanding is that if you ever want to do a backdoor Roth, you don't want deductible funds in a Traditional account, because you can't choose to convert only the taxable funds.

From the [bogleheads wiki](http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Backdoor_Roth_IRA#Caution):

> If you have any other (non-Roth) IRAs, the taxable portion of any
>   conversion you make is prorated over all your IRAs; you cannot convert
>   just the non-deductible amount. In order to benefit from the
>   backdoor, you must either convert your other IRAs as well (which may
>   not be a good idea, as you are usually in a high tax bracket if you
>   need to use the backdoor), or else transfer your deductible IRA
>   contributions to an employer plan such as a 401(k) (which may cost you
>   if the 401(k) has poor investment options).

Comment: +1 - I won't correct you, you are right. This is why I'd focus on pretax inside the 401(k), thus avoiding the potential backdoor tax issue.